# Finding the Derivative of a Function Where the x is a Number.

Tags: calculus

If I was to find d/dx g(1) for example, would I first find the value of the function g(x) at x=1 and then find the derivative of that which becomes 0 because the result would probably be a constant. Or do I first find the derivative of g(x) and then plug in x=1 to calculate it.

Thanks

Comment: The second thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential operator is a function, which maps a function to a function. So if you have a function $g(x)$ and you want to evaluate its derivative $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$ at a specific value, you use the derivative. I hope this gives you some intuition. In your words, you find the derivative of $g(x)$ and then plug in $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual notation is $g'(1)$ which means evaluate $g'(x)$ at $x=1$.

Remark that $\Big(g(1)\Big)'=\text{cst}'=0$ for any function $g$, so this surely not what you have in mind, derivatives would not be very useful with this definition.

With the $dx$ notation the parenthesing and/or the location of $g$ and $1$ matters:

- most used notation is probably $g'(1)=\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)_{x=1}$ or $\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}g(x)\right)_{x=1}\quad$, I think $\ \dfrac{dg}{dx}(1)$ is possible but less common.
- $(g(1))'=\dfrac{d(g(1))}{dx}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\color{blue}(g(1)\color{blue})=0$

The blue parenthesis may be omitted but I guess this is the origin of confusion.